# WCF cannot connect to endpoint after successfully adding service reference

Tags: wcf, client, endpoint

I've successfully published a WCF service on our production server.  I can navigate to the page and see the default WCF page.

I can add the service via "Add Service Reference" to a client on my computer.  I can also "Update Service Reference" with no problems what so ever.

The service was confirmed to work on my local computer with and without the client by running the default debugger that comes with VS2010.

When trying to call a service method (from the server hosted service), I receive this exception..

There was no endpoint listening at  that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

InnerException...

{"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."}

I've also tried running a client on the server itself to see if I can connect but I get the same error.

I even tried just deploying the basic WCF service that's created for you when you create a WCF service library (very basic), changed nothing, deployed successfully, and get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?  I've went down the road of IIS configurations, SSL certificates, etc but nothing seems to fix it.  I feel as though I'm missing something very basic here.

EDIT CLIENT CONFIG...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"     sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                         maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                 </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://SERVER_NAME.DOMAIN_NAME.com/TestService/TestService.Service1.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is your binding is it self hosted is there a firewall on the binding port that isn't an issue for http?

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Please see above.  The port is open on the firewall as other traffic can get through without a problem.

Comment: What is your service's config file?  That's where the problem most likely lies.

Answer (score 0):

Some pitfalls to check:

1) Check if the service URL is correct on your configuration files. This includes the protocol. It happened to me recently: the .config file had "http://" and the webserver was only accessible through HTTPS.

2) Disable the "required client certificate" setting on IIS.

3) If your service is inside an asp.net application, check if there are any restrictions of Authentication / Authorization in place. Allow anonymous access to your .SVC